# Can't link latex document up to bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I used latex years ago and am trying to use it again but I am having troubles. I was able to get the document formed and working in APA like I wanted using apa6 (although page numbers are alternating sides which I didn't want). But I can't get my bibliography to sync up. If I move my bib file into the file with the tex file itself, I can get it to work. But I want to keep the Bibliography file in the parent folder.

I have been trying a bunch of different forms of pathway but I can't seem to get any to work and I can't understand why because I am so new at this again. I have tried other threads but they all seem to complicated or what they say doesn't seem to work.

Currently I am trying `\bibliography{~/Dropbox/PhD/PhD-Bibliography}` and variations there of (such as including the .bib) but it keeps coming up as couldn't open database file.

Thank-you for any and all help.
[image]

Comment: This is not clear: have you compiled the bibliography with bibtex?

Comment: The bibliography was built using BibDesk if that is what you mean. When I try to switch running Bibtex to gather references is when the errors come up saying it cannot open a database file at that location and cannot find my cite keys. Does that make more sense? Sorry, new at this....

Comment: `~` in `~/Dropbox/PhD/PhD-Bibliography` gets expanded, which is a problem.

Comment: So do I drop it then and put in the whole path? but the path has spaces because the whole path I believe is "Macintosh HD/Users/Kyle/Dropbox...."

Comment: Try `\protect~/...`...

Comment: I tried putting the \protect in the bibliography line \bibliography{\protect~/Dropbox/PhD/PhD-Bibliography} but it didn't help. I also tried reversing the slashes in the pathway cause I thought I had read that can matter. I also tried putting the protect line as its own line but that didn't seem to do anything either (didn't know if you meant to do that)....

Comment: Renaming the machine from "Macintosh HD" to, say, "MacintoshHD", should be trivial to do. (Just click on the name below the hard-disk symbol and start editing.) Any other spaces anywhere in the fully qualified path?

Comment: @Mico I have tried that as well and I can't find any other spaces in the pathway, if I "Get Info" on my Bib file its pathway is "MacintoshHD ▸ Users ▸ Kyle ▸ Dropbox ▸ PhD" and then PhD-Bibliography.bib. The command I have in my document is "\bibliography{MacintoshHD/Users/Kyle/Dropbox/PhD/PhD-Bibliography}". I have also put the .bib extension on the end as well with no luck. Keep getting the same error as above in the image.... Thank-you for all the help so far though!

Answer (score 1):

I found a website after hours of searching having to do with Mendeley and latex that had a screenshot with the pathway in it and I got it to work in case anyone else is having the issue.

The line that finally worked was "\bibliography{/Users/Kyle/Dropbox/PhD/PhD-Bibliography}"...